# How to display a histogram containing multiple options and by gender

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, histogram, data-analysis

I have a xlsx file containing 2 columns: Gender( Male or Female) and A Question(with 4 categorical options, for reference lets say they are 'A', 'D', 'G', 'I'). 
How do I make 2 histograms in python(one for each of the genders), showing the number of people of that gender who chose each of those categories.
Also how to make pie charts using the same requirements?

Answer (score 0):

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(24,6))
dff=df.loc[df.Gender=='Male']
ax=axes.flatten()[0]
dff['Question'].hist()
ax=axes.flatten()[1]
dff.groupby('Question')['Gender'].count().plot(kind='pie',ax=ax)


dff=df.loc[df.Gender=='Male']
ax=axes.flatten()[2]
dff['Question'].hist()
ax=axes.flatten()[3]
dff.groupby('Question')['Gender'].count().plot(kind='pie',ax=ax)
```